# Walking through go struct fields with reflect doesn't match case map[string]interface{}

Tags: go

I have unusual task:
1. parse json message to Go struct
2. verify that all fields in JSON are within specific limits:
- string fields length no longer fixed constant
- maps contain no more than fixed number elements
- if values of map keys are nested structs verify for above 2 rules

To do this I use reflect, then iterating over elements, 
and doing type checking:
- if int or float - nothing to do - no verification
- if string - verify length (and return if failed)
- if map verify map length (and return if failed), then iterate over map values and recursively check if their fields violate string/map rules
- default (I assume that this is struct nested JSON structure): convert it to interface slice and do recursive call.

Problem: 
In JSON, I would have different map value types like: 
- map[string]MyStruct1
- map[string]MyStruct2
- etc.

So when I'm doing type checking I write:
case map[string]interface{}

But in my program this case is never matched and goes to case default, 
causing some error.

Any possible way to match type with case - map[string]interface{} ????

Here is my code for reference: 
http://play.golang.org/p/IVXHLBRuPK

```
func validate(vals []interface{}) bool {
result := true
    for _, elem := range vals {
        switch v := elem.(type) {
        case int, float64:
            fmt.Println("Got int or float: ", v)
        case string:
            fmt.Println("Got string", v)
            if len(elem.(string)) > 5 {
                fmt.Println("String rule Violation!")
                result = false
                break
                fmt.Println("After Break")
            }
        case map[string]interface{}:
            fmt.Println("Got map", v)
            if len(elem.(map[string]interface{})) > 1 || !validate(elem.([]interface{})) {
                fmt.Println("Map length rule Violation!")
                result = false
                break
            }
        default:
            fmt.Println("Got struct:", v)

            // Convert to interface list all other structures no string/int/float/map:
            new_v := reflect.ValueOf(elem)
            new_values := make([]interface{}, new_v.NumField())
            for j := 0; j < new_v.NumField(); j++ {
                new_values[j] = new_v.Field(j).Interface()
            }

            // Recursively call for validate nested structs
            if !validate(new_values) {
                result = false
                break
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("After Break 2")
    return result
}



func main() {
// Test truct:
x := C{1, B{"abc", A{10, 0.1, map[string]Host{"1,2,3,4": Host{"1.2.3.4"}}}}}

// Conversion:
v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
values := make([]interface{}, v.NumField())
for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    values[i] = v.Field(i).Interface()
}

// Validate function verification
fmt.Println(validate(values))
}
```

In this example I can't ever reach case: map[string]interface{}

Big kudos on helpful suggestions!

Comment: Add your code to your question (SO prefers code here rather than linked to elsewhere)

Comment: done, put main code part in question body

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `case map[string]interface{}` won't match `map[string]Host` so it will get parsed as a struct, which it isn't.

You will either have to check `new_v.Kind()` and handle maps via reflection or add a special case for `map[string]Host`.